# How to create m3u8 playlist from multiple segment.mp4 files with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, m3u8

We are storing a cameras stream as segment files using these ffmpeg output args (only listing relevant args) `-f segment -segment_time 10 -segment_format mp4`

All of the questions I've found are about creating an m3u8 playlist from a single .mp4 file. I would like to avoid concatenation as that will introduce too much latency. Is the best way to convert each segment into a .ts file separately and build the m3u8 manually, or does ffmpeg support this?

Comment: Have you tried pass the `-segment_list` option to the [segment](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Options-60) muxer? The muxer is not aware about the type of video stream source.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Having exactly the same problem…

Comment: No, unfortunately I could not find how to do this with ffmpeg directly. Instead just using nginx vod-module to serve these now